# Copy/Paste multiple rows in VBA

Tags: vba, copy, rows

I am attempting to do a simple copy row, paste row within a workbook. I've searched threads and tried changing my code multiple times to no avail.

The one that comes closest to working is this but it only copies a single instance of matching criteria.

I am trying to create a loop that will copy all of the rows that has a match in one of the columns.

So, if 8 columns, each row with matching value in column 7 should copy to a named sheet.

```html
Sub test()
Set MR = Sheets("Main").Range("H1:H1000")
Dim WOLastRow As Long, Iter As Long

    For Each cell In MR
    
If cell.Value = "X" Then
cell.EntireRow.Copy
Sheets("X").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).PasteSpecial
    End If
If cell.Value = "Y" Then
cell.EntireRow.Copy
Sheets("Y").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).PasteSpecial
    End If
If cell.Value = "Z" Then
cell.EntireRow.Copy
Sheets("Z").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).PasteSpecial
    End If
If cell.Value = "AB" Then
cell.EntireRow.Copy
Sheets("AB").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).PasteSpecial
    End If
    
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Next

End Sub
```

I like this because I need to target multiple destination sheets with different criteria but I need all rows that match criteria to copy over.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED CODE IN RESPONSE TO NEW REQUEST:

The code below will copy all of the rows in Sheet `Main` and paste them into the corresponding worksheets based on the value in Column 7.

Do note: If there is a value in Column 7 that does NOT match to an existing sheet name, the code will throw an error. Modify the code to handle that exception.

Let me know of any additional needed help.

```
Sub CopyStuff()
    Dim wsMain As Worksheet
    Dim wsPaste As Worksheet
    Dim rngCopy As Range
    Dim nLastRow As Long
    Dim nPasteRow As Long
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Const COLUMN_TO_LOOP As Integer = 7

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wsMain = Worksheets("Main")
    nLastRow = wsMain.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngCopy = wsMain.Range("A2:H" & nLastRow)

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If UCase(ws.Name) = "MAIN" Then
            'Do Nothing for now
        Else
            Intersect(ws.UsedRange, ws.Columns("A:H")).ClearContents
        End If
    Next ws

    For Each rngCell In Intersect(rngCopy, Columns(COLUMN_TO_LOOP))
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wsPaste = Worksheets(rngCell.Value)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If wsPaste Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox ("Sheet name: " & rngCell.Value & " does not exist")
        Else

            nPasteRow = wsPaste.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

            wsMain.Range("A" & rngCell.Row).Resize(, 8).Copy wsPaste.Cells(nPasteRow, 1)
        End If

        Set wsPaste = Nothing
    Next rngCell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. It's just giving me a run-teime error'9': subscript out of range for the Set wsPaste=Worksheets(rngCell.Value).

Comment: Is there a worksheet with the name of the value in Column 7 for each row in Column 7. To reference the example in your original post, the cell in Column G has an 'X' value. That row is move to a Sheet named 'X'. Does this hold true for all rows? Also, did any of the rows get copied to any of the worksheets?

Comment: so it did copy the first instance over. So the first X value was pasted in the X sheet. So in the test workbook I'm using, I have 11 instances of X in column G. each time I run it, it will copy that same instance below the first one on the destination sheet.

Comment: Do you have any blank cells in Column G? I created a test workbook using all of the information that I gathered from your original post, and it worked with no problems. This leads me to believe I misunderstood your initial data layout. On a side note, I modified the code and edited my original answer. This new version will check if the sheet exists, and show a message box when the sheet doesn't. Take note of the messages of sheet names that don't exist.

Comment: That was perfect. There was one example that a sheet and reference didn't match. Runs beautifully. Thank you! One follow up request. Is it possible to clear the destination cells before pasting? I would like to avoid duplicating the pasted info.

Comment: I edited the code above in response. Before copying anything over, the code loops through the Workbook and clears all cells that are NOT in the worksheet `Main`. With that said, if you have ANY worksheets in the workbook aside from `Main` that you do NOT want cleared, then you have to amend the code before running it. Otherwise, it's good to go! On a side note, if the code works as needed, please mark the question as answered so that future readers can use the question as a reference.

Comment: That last update cleared all sheets and reference data, with no pasting. hahaha. a bit shocking to see at first.

Comment: It cleared the Main sheet as well? If that's the case, that explains why it copied nothing over (there was nothing left to copy). But, it doesn't explain why it deleted information in the `Main` sheet. Is it named, exactly, Main (case sensitive)?

Comment: Thanks User. It was my mistake. I misspelled the second reference to the main sheet in your code. Quick question. Can I just clear the destination cells and not the entire destination worksheet? There will be a separate section of that destination worksheet that I will have formula's in.

Comment: it actually seems to clear all worksheets that aren't going to have data pasted from the main sheet.

Comment: The code clears ALL worksheets that aren't named `Main`. Is that what you need?

Comment: No I would just hope to clear the area it is being pasted into. So the A2:H area that is being copied. From I:ZZ I will have other formulas using the data being pasted into A2:H.

Comment: Ok, edited again. Hopefully, this fits the bill. I made a couple of changes, actually. First, I only deleted contents in sheets NOT named `Main` and only data in columns A:H. In addition, I change the Copy/Paste code. Initially, it copied the entirerow, and pasted it. This served to overwrite the data in the Paste sheets, including columns I:Z (since they are part of the entire row). The new code no longer overwrites these  formula cells.

Comment: well it does only clear out the area that was copied, so that part works. unfortunately it also clears out the section to be copied, so nothing is pasted, and the original data is now removed.

Comment: The original data, referring to the data coming from worksheet `Main`, correct? Did you confirm that the sheet name is exactly `Main` (Case sensitive, no leading/trailing spaces)?

Comment: yea. now it is giving me an run time error 1004: cannot do that to a merged cell, even though there is no merged cell. I have unmerged every sheet to make sure. The line it is referencing is Intersect (ws.UsedRange,ws.Columns("A:H")).ClearContents

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is pasting to the same row in each sheet over and over, to the last row with a value in column A. `Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)` says, roughly "go to the very bottom of the spreadsheet in column A, and then jump up from there to the next lowest cell in column A with contents," which gets you back to the same cell each time.

Instead, you could use lines of the pattern:

```
Sheets("X").Range("A" & Sheets("X").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1).PasteSpecial
```

Where [`UsedRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732%28v=office.15%29.aspx) is a range containing all of the cells on the sheet with data in them. The `+ 1` puts you on the following row.

You could make this a little prettier using [`With`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx):

```
With Sheets("X")    
  .Range("A" & .UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1).PasteSpecial    
End With
```